# Iteratively update a scalaz Tree

Tags: scala, scalaz, zipper

I have a list of paths:

```
val paths = List(List("foo"), List("bar", "a"), List("bar", "b"))
```

I want to represent that in a scalaz Tree:

```
def pathsToTree(root: String, paths: List[List[String]]): Tree[String] = ???
```

Result:

```
pathsToTree("paths", paths)

=> "paths".node("foo".leaf, "bar".node("a".leaf, "b".leaf))
```

I've read some about `TreeLoc` from http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Tree.html but it seems pretty tedious using left/right or child indices. I imagine doing something like:

```
paths.foldLeft(root.node()) { case (acc: Tree[String], path: List[String]) =>
  acc // how to add all the items from `path` to the tree?
}
```

It looks like I could use `find` and `setTree` or `modifyTree` but that seems quite inefficient.

Answer (score 3):

This is general builder:

```
  def pathTree[E](root: E, paths: Seq[Seq[E]]): Tree[E] =
    root.node(paths groupBy (_.head) map {
      case (parent, subpaths) => pathTree(parent, subpaths collect {
        case parent +: rest if rest.nonEmpty => rest
      })
    } toSeq: _*)
```

for online modifing we can define:

```
  def addPath[E](path: Seq[E], tree: Tree[E]): Tree[E] = if (path.isEmpty) tree
  else
    tree match {
      case Tree.Node(root, children) if children.exists(_.rootLabel == path.head) => root.node(
        children map (subtree => if (subtree.rootLabel == path.head) addPath(path.tail, subtree) else subtree): _*
      )
      case Tree.Node(root, children) => root.node(children :+ path.init.foldRight(path.last.leaf)((root, sub) => root.node(sub)): _*)
    }
```

so

```
  val tree = pathTree("root", List(List("foo"), List("bar", "a"), List("bar", "b", "c")))
  println(tree.drawTree)
```

yields

```
"root"
|
+- "foo"
|
`- "bar"
   |
   +- "b"
   |  |
   |  `- "c"
   |
   `- "a"
```

and  `println(addPath(Seq("foo","baz"), tree).drawTree)` prints

```
"root"
|
+- "foo"
|  |
|  `- "baz"
|
`- "bar"
   |
   +- "b"
   |  |
   |  `- "c"
   |
   `- "a"
```

Comment: Note there is a missing `)` in addPath at `if children.exists(_.rootLabel == path.head`. I can't edit because edits must change more than 6 characters :(